# Finding non-commutative finite-dimensional "hypersurface" algebras

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, polynomials

Fix a field $K$.
Call a non-commutative polynomial $f(x_i)$ whose monomial terms are all of degree at least 2 in the variables $x_i$ magic if the finite dimensional $K$-algebra $A_{f,n}:=K<x_i>/(x_i^n,f(x_i))$ is admissible and finite dimensional for all $n \geq 2$. Here $K<x_i>$ is the non-commutative polynomial ring in the variables $x_i$ and admissible means that $J^r \subseteq (x_i^n,f(x_i))$ for some $r \geq 2$ where $J$ is the ideal generated by the $x_i$.

For example for two variables, the polynomial $f(x,y)=xy+y^2+y^2x$ should be magical (A_{f,n} should have dimension n^2), while the polynomial $f(x,y)=xy^2+y^2+y^2x$ is not.

Call two magical polynomials $g,f$ isomorphic if the algebras $A_{f,n_i}:=K<x_i>/(x_i^{n_i},f(x_i))$ and $A_{g,n_i}:=K<x_i>/(x_i^{n_i},g(x_i))$ are isomorphic as $K$-algebras for all $n_i \geq 2$. It seems that most magical polynomials I can find in two variables are isomorphic, but I can not make this precise.

> Question: Is there are nice characterisation or at least an easy way to produce magical polynomials?

In particular, can magical polynomials of degree $\leq 3$ be classified with field coefficients only 1 or -1?

Any other nice examples of magical polynomials are welcome. Do you know a non-trivial example for greater than two variables?

Checking whether a polynomial is magical in 3 or more variables even for fixed $n$ is extremely hard it seems, even with a computer (unless there is a nice trick of course).

You can use GAP and its package QPA to check finite dimensional and the admissible property as in the following example:

```
LoadPackage("qpa");
Q := Quiver(1, [[1,1,"x"],[1,1,"y"]]);
KQ := PathAlgebra(GF(3),Q);AssignGeneratorVariables(KQ);
rels:=[x^5,y^5,x*y*x+x^2*y^2*x+y*x];A:=KQ/rels;
Dimension(A);IsAdmissibleQuotientOfPathAlgebra(A);
```